# Mysql insert into with values containing double commas

Tags: mysql, perl, csv, sql-insert

I am trying to insert values into a `MySQL` table line by line, that is read from a `CSV` file in `Perl`. If any field is empty in CSV file, there will be two consecutive commas. E.g.

```
Firstname,Lastname,Code,Phone,Email
fname1,lname1,123,34543,f1@gmail.com
fname2,lname2,344,45645,f2@gmail.com
fname3,lname3,454,,f3@gmail.com
```

In the third row, there is no phone no. So there is two consecutive commas. When we try to insert into mysql with following command, it fails.

```
insert into table1 (Firstname,Lastname,Code,Phone,Email) values (fname3,lname3,454,,f3@gmail.com)
```

How to do that?

I have used following code to do that.

```
open CSV, $file or die $!;
my @csv_content = <CSV>;
close CSV;
my $fields = "Firstname,Lastname,Code,Phone,Email";
my $table = "table1";

my $csv = Text::CSV->new();
foreach(@csv_content){
   if($csv->parse($_)){
         my @values = $csv->fields();
         my $status = $csv->combine(@values);
         my $line = $csv->string();

         $statement = "INSERT INTO $table($fields) VALUES($line);";
         $sth = $dbh->prepare( $statement );
         $sth->execute() or die "$! $DBI::errstr";
    }
}
```

Comment: MySQL can load a CSV directly with the LOAD DATA INFILE syntax. I would recommend using that unless you need to preprocess your CSV somehow.

Comment: I need to pre-process csv so that is not an option.

Comment: 1/ Use bind points in your SQL. 2/ `prepare()` the SQL outside of the loop (the second point isn't solving your problem - it's improving the efficiency of your code).

Answer (score 1):

I might write it this way. I included the empty fields in the your csv file. I've used 5 placeholders, '?', and did not prepare inside the loop. Just execute in the loop.

```
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1, eol => "\n" } );

my $file = 'blahblah';
open my $fh, $file or die "$file open failed: $!";

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=pedro.lite","","",
    {PrintError => 1, AutoCommit => 0}) or die "Can't connect";


my $sth = $dbh->prepare(q{INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)})
    or die $dbh->errstr;

<$fh>; # throw away header - first line
while (my $row = $csv->getline ($fh)) {
     $sth->execute(@$row) or die $sth->errstr;
}

$dbh->commit or die $dbh->errstr;
close $fh or die "$file close failed: $!";
$sth->finish;
```

If there's no header at the beginning of the file, don't use that line of code.

**Update:** Here is an actual program I used to create a database, (using SQLite), and it worked fine, even with the double commas, (empty field).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV_XS;
use DBI;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ( { binary => 1, eol => "\n" } );

my $file = 'j1.csv';
open my $fh, $file or die "$file open failed: $!";

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=pedro.lite","","",
    {RaiseError => 1, PrintError => 0, AutoCommit => 0}) or die "Can't connect";

$dbh->do('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1');

$dbh->do(<<EOF);
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    Firstname TEXT,
    Lastname TEXT,
    Code INTEGER,
    Phone INTEGER,
    Email TEXT)
EOF

my $sth = $dbh->prepare(q{INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)});

<$fh>; # throw away header - first line
while (my $row = $csv->getline ($fh)) {
     $sth->execute(@$row);
}
$sth->finish;
$dbh->commit;
$dbh->disconnect;

close $fh or die "$file close failed: $!";
```

And here is the output from a query of table1.

```
sqlite> .mode column
sqlite> .width 10 10 10 10 14
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> select * from table1;
Firstname   Lastname    Code        Phone       Email
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  --------------
fname1      lname1      123         34543       f1@gmail.com
fname2      lname2      344         45645       f2@gmail.com
fname3      lname3      454                     f3@gmail.com
sqlite>
```

As you can see, it correctly shows that there is no phone number for fname3.
I used your data just as it appears in your post to INSERT into table1.

Answer (score 1):

The computer does not understand what you are trying to insert because it cannot understand that there is empty value in between the two commas. If your are doing this from `perl`, then try to enclose each value within `quotes`, even the empty ones. For an example in your data line 3 change

```
fname3,lname3,454,,f3@gmail.com
```

to

```
'fname3','lname3','454','','f3@gmail.com'
```

This is easy to achieve in any programming language. Now try to insert. It will not throw exception as the part between them will be empty string.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to load such data might be to use the mysql command `LOAD DATA INFILE`:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "yourfilename" INTO TABLE "yourtablename" COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ",";
```

Thus avoiding the ,, issue completely

Comment: I need to do that from perl, doing it directly is not an option.

Comment: Then you will have to pre-process the line in perl into different columns first: Split into array by , and then assign the array values to values in your insert statement. That way you avoid the empty column issue since you will just be assigning an empty value to a column instead.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with another approach: first enclosed each field in inverted quotes, even the empty ones. The data looked like this after enclosing in quotes:

```
'fname1','lname1','123','34543','f1@gmail.com'
'fname2','lname2','344','45645','f2@gmail.com'
'fname3','lname3','454','','f3@gmail.com'
```

This was done with the programming language. After this step, there was no problem inserting the data.

Answer (score 0):

enclose every value by inverted comma like 'fname3','lname3','454','','f3@gmail.com'. Note here the empty inverted commas in between commas. This will do the trick